# Misaligned Figure number with caption problem [SOLVED]

Tags: floats, captions

I'm encountering a strange issue where long captions break the alignment with the Figure label:

[image: Broken Caption]
though shorter captions behave correctly:
[image: Not Broken Caption]

I also get an "overfull \hbox" warning with the overflowed caption. The implementation is vanilla:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Chapter3/Figures/lenna.png}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in velit imperdiet, scelerisque neque id, semper ante. Nullam eu metus et lorem semper consectetur. Integer vitae augue a arcu volutpat eleifend non ac risus. Nullam et urna dolor. Nunc sagittis quis est eu accumsan. Suspendisse eu dapibus est, quis feugiat orci. Cras mollis viverra accumsan. Morbi rhoncus turpis nec dolor finibus, sit amet hendrerit magna mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec sagittis, metus in dignissim accumsan, leo leo fringilla lacus, eu maximus risus massa ac ante.}
\end{figure}
```

though it's part of a very long document with a custom styling sheet that is hard to decipher, but mandated (disseration format). Thoughts on why this may be happening?

SOLUTION: The packages that were hyperref and bookmark, removing them fixed the issue.

Comment: Without a minimum working example, this is just guesswork, since e..g. `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Lorem ipsum.... (rest of text here).}
\end{figure}
\end{document}` works fine.

Comment: most caption styles (including the one in the basic article class) have two styles, in article by default if it is small enough to fit in one line the line including the figure number is centred, but larger captions are set fully justified in a parbox, and the parbox itself then centred. That is what is happening in your case but the parbox alignment looks a little weird but with no example impossible to guess why.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Unfortunately dissecting or posting my entire PhD thesis might be too cumbersome,  but this gives me a good lead. I didn't know there were two styles!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP declare that  comments give him a way, how to solve his problems with caption styles.